# Manipulating the cloning function

Tags: jquery

This lines of code displayes textbox and subject name for the category selected by user:

```
for (i = 0; i < globalStore.data.length; i++) {
        //alert(globalStore.data[i].catname);  
        $("#sub").append("<div class='sub row clone_this' id='"+globalStore.data[i].subid+"' ><div class='small-5 medium-3 large-3 columns'><input type='text' onfocusout='getText("+globalStore.data[i].subid+")' class='text_"+globalStore.data[i].subid+"' placeholder='RM'></div><div class='small-7 medium-9 large-9 columns'>"+globalStore.data[i].subname+"</div></div>");
     }
```

I want to allow user to specify price for each subject of their choice. Then 'onfocusout' that particular row should move to the top. I achived this by using the clone() function. 
However I want some modification done after clone to the cloned element as well as the original element that was cloned from.

Cloned item: The textbox must be replaced with  tag. Meaning, instead of  a textbox showing the value keyed in by user, it outght to show a link of the value keyed in instead followed by a delete/remove icon beside each subject name.

And to the original element that was cloned from, should hide itself/remove.WHne the remove/delete link clicked in the above moved cloned item, then this would appear back.

current problems are:

1) when clicked on remove link, it removes the item and refreshes the page.How to prevent it from reloading?

2) Top few rows of subjects are not cloning. Not sure why

Clone function

```
function getText(param)
{
  $("div.clone_this#"+param).clone(true, true).append("<a href='' onclick=removeThis('"+param+"')>remove</a>").insertBefore("#sub");
}
function removeThis(param)
{
    $("div.clone_this#"+param).remove();
}
```

Comment: subject line and body content seem unrelated.

Comment: @Dragon thank you, I didn't realize that..